# Integrate ASP.net MVC4 with Orchard CMS 1.6 as seperate sites

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, orchardcms-1.6

I would like an existing ASP.net MVC4 site to showpartials views from Orchard CMS. Is there a way I could have multiple ASP.net MVC4 sites talking to one Master Orcharch CMS website in a different domains?
I DO NOT want to create ASP.net MVC4 site as seperate module and integrate it into Orchard CMS website. I would like to have on Master Orchard CMS and have other ASP.net websites to show partial views of Orchard CMS. Is this scenario possible with latest Orchard CMS website or is there any other .NET CMS systems that supports this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

MVC 4 is only supported in  Orchard in version 1.6 and you should upgrade to 1.6.1 for security reasons.

I am pretty certain that what you are asking for is not in line with how Orchard is designed to work - and hence is not supported.

Very simply put the website IS Orchard CMS and MVC projects ARE modules within it; making a master is silly when modules are extensible.

A possible solution to your problem is to create some web service (AKA master) that services other Orchard sites.

Better still, decouple your base website application, and enable the parts you need on a per site basis.